# How to get the type supporting an enum

Tags: c++

I want to write a test to detect the underlying type of a enum and that test case should be compiler-agnostic.

I cannot use `std::underlying_type`, `__underlying_type` and other compiler specific implementation

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::underlying_type`? It is literally the perfect tool for your case

Comment: please explain what you want to achieve, this smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to get the underlying type but you dont want `underlying_type`, so what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to get the the underlying type of any enum without using std::underlying_type.

Comment: Thanks @bruno. Updating the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC has `__underlying_type (type)` as a compiler intrinsic. Intrinsics are special functions that the compiler implements internally.

Other compilers probably work in a similar way.

Comment: I want to write a test to detect the underlying type of a enum and that test case should be compiler-agnostic

Comment: `std::underlying_type` is the compiler agnostic way of doing this. Each platform will implement this in terms of its own compiler intrinsics. If you want to implement your test using intrinsics, you will have to do so for each platform you are supporting. #ifdef will then be your friend.

Comment: Cool.. This will help

Answer (score 6):

This is implementation-defined. For clang, it's implemented [via the `__underlying_type(type)` compiler feature](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checks-for-type-trait-primitives), for example. [Likewise for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Type-Traits.html).

The main reason not to use `std::underlying_type` from the standard library would be in environments where there is no standard library available. (Embedded, kernel, etc.) Usually in that situation you'll be targeting a closed set of compilers, so you can just reimplement `std::underlying_type` for each compiler you're targeting individually, using each compiler's necessary implementation-specific features.

Comment: Isn't using anything that starts with a double underscore undefined behavior? Strictly speaking that is

Comment: @Ayxan No, it's just that all names containing `__` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Ayxan - it's just a namespace of identifiers reserved to the implantation. The implementation can either use it internally or expose functions with those names. The UB is if *you* try to *define* such names, not if you use implementation provided ones.